# Animação 3D com C++

Tags: c++, api, animação, 3d, blender

Olá, alguém conhece alguma API em C++ que eu possa fazer animações 3D? Se possível com suporte ao blender.
Já usei o Horde3D no entanto a API dele é complicada, toda vez que eu editava era preciso compilar para poder usar no meu projeto. Espero ter sido especifico, desde já obrigado.